# How to use a script shell or a jenkins plugin to create or to delete a sonarqube project?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I have many project of Sonarqube, each project correspond to a a version of my software.

At the same moment, I save the last 5 version of my software. I use jenkins for integration continue.

My aims it to delete or to create a sonarqube project by a script or a jenkins plugins

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give more details about what exactly you want to "manage"

Comment: I  want to kown if there is a way to use script shell to delete or to create a sonarqube project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projects are created on their first analysis. If you need to create them before that, you can Provision them via the UI or via web services, which will also let you delete projects: https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/projects

So your script simply needs to invoke the web services with the proper permissions.